# Keeping original URL

Tags: plugins, urls

I have a domain example.com which is built in Wordpress. It has several menu pages such as contact, registration, about.

1. If I click on the about, the URL in the address bar to read example.com/about.
2. If I click on the registration, the URL in the address bar to read example.com/registration.
3. If I click on the contact page, the URL in the address bar to read example.com/contact.

How can I keep the original URL whenever I click on any page?
It would be the same as the below explanation.

1. If I click on the contact page, the URL in the address bar to read example.com/home.
2. If I click on the registration, the URL in the address bar to read example.com/home.
3. If I click on the about, the URL in the address bar to read example.com/home.

Help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can edit your menus to all have links leading to example.com/home. But what's the point of these links then? Or do you want the content to be changed, while keeping the same URL? You'd need a custom AJAX script for that.

Comment: I am developing a website in localhost. If the website is published in someday, the address appears on each page will be changed.
Specifically, a user loads the website with address example.com, then he clicks on the contact page. Will the address change to localhost/contact?

Comment: If you are migrating the database with these changes it's possible your site url could go with them. In that case you would just want to use http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/ or make your paths relative.

Comment: Then just don't use absolute links, in your menus either refer pages or use relative links (for example, just `/about` instead of `example.com/about`). If you don't use absolute links (both in code and in the dashboard) then after moving your local website to the server you'd need to only change 2 values in WP options (there are multiple ways of doing that and it's easy to google). Otherwise you'd need to search-replace, like @jgraup said and it's also quite straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about localhost vs. remote after migration then make your links relative.

In the case where you are using the standard [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) like;

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu' => 'test'
));
```

Filter the HTML from [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu/) to make all the links relative.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', function( $nav_menu, $args ){

    // get the current site
    $site_url = get_site_url();

    // remove from all links
    $relative_menu = str_ireplace($site_url, '', $nav_menu);

    // return relative menu
    return $relative_menu;

});
```

If you want to always point to a specific URL no matter when the site is located (local or remote) then add custom links to your [menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) as absolute paths.

[image]